# attach function addEventListener

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

trying to automate IE with excel vba
had some checking and reading and stuck how to program it work in the way i need

assuming here is no event attached in the original of html , how i can add event listener ? i knew there could be other way to do it , but i would like to explore this event listener functionality since i cannot shared the original html where the other method does'nt work

here is the html for testing

when click it (if there is click event) if should change the two into three 
i purposely left out the click event for this testing , so please do not amend the html

html

++++++

```
<title> Test </title>

<table id="outside">
  <tr><td id="t1">one</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="t2">two</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
function modifyText() {
  var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
  if (t2.firstChild.nodeValue == "three") {
    t2.firstChild.nodeValue = "two";
  } else {
    t2.firstChild.nodeValue = "three";
  }
}
</script>
```

try below not working

```
objIE.getElementById("t2").addEventListener "click", modifyText, False
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use value.
`var t2 = document.getElementById("t2").value`

Comment: hi . thanks for suggestion. i am doing interaction between vba vs html , so not modifying the source code in html (and i cant in actual scenario)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `Call IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("modifyText();", "JavaScript")` commands to execute the JavaScript function.

More detail information, please check the following sample code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim IE As Object 
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "<the website url>"

        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        'using Debug.Print method to find the element and check the value.
        'Debug.Print IE.document.getElementbyId("t1").innerText
        'Find the t1 node and change the innerText value.
        IE.document.getElementbyId("t1").innerText = "three"

        Call IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("modifyText();", "JavaScript")

    End With
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

The website resource as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="outside">
        <tr><td id="t1">one</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="t2">two</td></tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        function modifyText() {
            var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
            if (t2.firstChild.nodeValue == "three") {
                t2.firstChild.nodeValue = "two";
            } else {
                t2.firstChild.nodeValue = "three";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result like this:

[image]

**Edit**: 
If you want to attach event to the html element from VBA, you could use the following code:

```
Call IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("document.getElementById('t2').addEventListener('click', modifyText);", "JavaScript")
```

Comment: hi thanks again =) . the purpose here is to learn how to code the event listener, where i think the actual scenario does not have the click event and i need to add the event listener

Comment: Try to use the following code: `Call IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("document.getElementById('t2').addEventListener('click', modifyText);", "JavaScript")`

Comment: Is there any error? Please check your web page resource, whether it using iframe tag or not? I have retested it on my side, it still works well (using IE 11.116.18362.0 version), the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxH2p.gif). You could try to create a new sample and using my code to check it.

Comment: weird, it does'nt work. can share your html , maybe i try and see

Comment: I have already shared you all of my code, please check the above reply.